# Issue Compiling Spring Boot to Native Image

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

I would like to preface this with how I'm relatively new to Spring Boot and GraalVM, and have been having issues with it. (I set it up using spring intializer). Whenever I try to use the Spring Boot native image to make my program into a native image, it gives me the following error (when running `mvn clean package -Pnative`):

```
'gu.cmd' tool wasn't found. This probably means that JDK at isn't a GraalVM distribution.
```

Additionally, if this helps at all I would like to generate a native image to be able to run locally or on a deployment server since I'm building an API.

So far, I've tried reinstalling GraalVM and the required plugins (I'm on Windows). I have installed the native-image in GraalVM using gu, and used the Spring Initializer to set up my project. Below are some outputs you may find useful:

Here's java version:

```
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.1 (build 19.0.2+7-jvmci-22.3-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.1 (build 19.0.2+7-jvmci-22.3-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here's my output when running `native-image --version`

```
GraalVM 22.3.1 Java 19 CE (Java Version 19.0.2+7-jvmci-22.3-b12)
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>peoplegeneratorapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>peoplegeneratorapi</name>
    <description>People generator API with Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.20131108.vaadin1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                <artifactId>asciidoctor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-docs</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process-asciidoc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <backend>html</backend>
                            <doctype>book</doctype>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-restdocs-asciidoctor</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-restdocs.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>compile-no-fork</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

And here's a working `mvn spring-boot:start` if this helps any:

```
C:\Users\XX\.jdks\graalvm-ce-19\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\XX\Documents\Code\peoplegeneratorapi -Djansi.passthrough=true -Dmaven.home=C:\Users\XX\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.8.7-bin\1ktonn2lleg549uah6ngl1r74r\apache-maven-3.8.7 -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\XX\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.8.7-bin\1ktonn2lleg549uah6ngl1r74r\apache-maven-3.8.7\bin\m2.conf "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=65445:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\XX\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.8.7-bin\1ktonn2lleg549uah6ngl1r74r\apache-maven-3.8.7\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\XX\.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.8.7-bin\1ktonn2lleg549uah6ngl1r74r\apache-maven-3.8.7\boot\plexus-classworlds.license org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2022.3.2 spring-boot:start
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< org.example:peoplegeneratorapi >---------------
[INFO] Building peoplegeneratorapi 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.4:start (default-cli) @ peoplegeneratorapi ---
[INFO] Attaching agents: []
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.4)

2023-03-04T12:15:52.890+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.example.peoplegenerator.Main   : Starting Main using Java 19.0.2 with PID 12652 (C:\Users\XX\Documents\Code\peoplegeneratorapi\target\classes started by XX in C:\Users\XX\Documents\Code\peoplegeneratorapi)
2023-03-04T12:15:52.893+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.example.peoplegenerator.Main   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-03-04T12:15:52.959+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-03-04T12:15:52.959+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-03-04T12:15:53.826+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-03-04T12:15:53.835+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-03-04T12:15:53.835+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-03-04T12:15:53.889+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-03-04T12:15:53.889+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 929 ms
2023-03-04T12:15:54.229+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-03-04T12:15:54.254+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-03-04T12:15:54.263+05:30  INFO 12652 --- [  restartedMain] o.example.peoplegenerator.Main   : Started Main in 1.741 seconds (process running for 21.409)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.047 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-04T12:15:54+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the output when running `mvn clean package -Pnative`:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.665 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-04T12:40:38+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.graalvm.buildtools:native-maven-plugin:0.9.20:compile-no-fork (build-native) on project peoplegeneratorapi: 'gu.cmd' tool wasn't found. This probably means that JDK at isn't a GraalVM distribution. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Edit: I'm not too sure how I might give a minimal reproducible example for this, so I tried my best to describe the issue as descriptively as possible.

Comment: Try setting `GRAALVM_HOME` and/or setting `JAVA_HOME` to point to GraalVM rather than plain JDK

Comment: @peterz I just tried setting my GRAALVM_HOME and my JAVA_HOME (which is already set for local and global), but still the same issue. For the record, I also tried this on linux with a different graalvm setup and had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `gu.cmd` must be in your `PATH` environment variable.

To do so, you need to add the `GRAALVM_HOME/bin` folder to your `PATH` variable.